# Change iframe content depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, ads

Hello I have a problem I have an ad that can't be resized, the support said that I can use 2 ads 1 for mobile 1 for desktop so the ads are 720 x 90 and the other one is 300 x 100 i want it to change depending on scree size to switch between this two:

```
<iframe border=0 frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 width=736 height=98 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true src=zzzz></iframe>
```

and

```
<iframe border=0 frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 width=300 height=100 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true src=iiiiii></iframe>
```

if anyone can help me I will really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  I've answered your question below.  If my answer solved your problem, please click the check mark to accept it.  If not, then please leave a comment below and I will help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code both of these items and hide one via CSS depending on the browser size.

```
<iframe class='lg' border=0 frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 width=736 height=98 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true src=zzzz></iframe>

<iframe class='sm' border=0 frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 width=300 height=100 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true src=iiiiii></iframe>
```

**CSS**:

```
@media (max-width: 719px) { //set max width to your preferred mobile width.  I used 719 because your large banner is 720.
    .lg {display:none;}
    .sm {display:initial;}
}

@media (min-width: 720px) { //set min width to be larger than the css rule above.
    .lg {display:initial;}
    .sm {display:none;}
}
```

Comment: Your code and example are different widths however.  The `@media` is used in responsive site design and in almost all browsers will change when you re-size the window.  Hope this helps!

Comment: My method uses CSS instead of Javascript which is a better choice in my opinion.

Comment: For these kinds of checks(display size etc) CSS is amazing. Lightweight and super fast. Imo its Always better to use CSS when its appliable.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked great, I think the same regarding css and javascript, using css is better then javascript imo, anyway thank you again!